# Page content is to wide for mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a prototype [website](https://shiftedreality007.github.io/martini/) where everything looks perfect on a desktop browser, but once I use an emulator for mobile devices, the content is too wide on the mobile screen and thus the user has to scroll horizontally.

I've used  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and tweaked around it by removing `content="width=device-width` or setting it to `content="1000` but no solution as it doesn't fit to the mobile device screen. I also tweaked  around with `initial-scale=1.0"` by setting the value lower than 1, like .41 and no result.

I tried `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` tag, but after applying it some of the content doesn't display, and it and doesn't fit as well.

Another issue I'm facing is at the div with "Our customers thoughts" it's slightly moved to the left and I want it to be right in the middle. I've tried `margin: auto` as well as `text-align: center` with no results.

Below is the code as well as some screenshots:

```css
@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/belligiant');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;300&family=Raleway:wght@100;200&display=swap');
@font-face {
  font-family: Nevrada;
  src: url('Nevrada.ttf'), url(Nevrada.otf);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  min-width: 475px;
  background-image: url(image1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  //border: solid 1px black;
  width: 1349px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.headcontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  //border: solid black 1px;
  //width: 22px;
  //height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: Belligiant, Arial;
  //text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  color: white;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  //border: white solid 1px;
  margin-left: 140px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.menu {
  //border: solid black 1px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.actioncontent {
  //border: solid black 1px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.actioncontent p {
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 1.5em;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 68px;
}

.actioncontent h1 {
  word-spacing: 2.5em;
  font-family: Nevrada;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  max-width: 100%
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.btn1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.btn1 a {
  text-shadow: 3px 5px 5px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 0.4em;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.btn1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.btn1 a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.btn1 .link {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.btn2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  word-spacing: 0.4em;
  margin-left: 36px;
}

hr {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  max-width: 110px;
}


/* end nav, actioncontent, content */


/* SERVICES */

.service {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1349px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #fdfbfb 0%, #ebedee 100%);
}

.service .choose {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.b {
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

.b:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.imgs img {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}


/* end services */


/* offers */

.offers {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1349px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(offers.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

span {
  color: #F58D00;
}

.offers .offers1 hr {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 26.5%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.offers .offers1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.flex1 {
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.flex1 .box .box1 .box2 {
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  background-image: url(pizza.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 120%;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box:hover {
  background-size: 155%;
}

.box1 {
  background-image: url(Sushi.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 140%;
  transition: all 4s cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box2 {
  background-image: url(fish.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 120%;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box2:hover {
  background-size: 155%;
}

.box h1,
.box p {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.box1 h1,
.box1 p {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.box1 .border {
  opacity: 0.0;
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  border: solid white 1px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
}

.box1:hover .border {
  opacity: 1.1;
  height: 30px;
  width: 78px;
}

.box1 p {
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.overlay hr {
  top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
}

.box:hover hr {
  width: 100%;
}

.hr {
  opacity: 0.0;
  left: 115px;
}

.hr1 {
  opacity: 0.0;
  right: 115px;
}

.box2:hover .hr {
  opacity: 1.1;
  width: 120%;
  left: 0px;
}

.box2:hover .hr1 {
  opacity: 1.1;
  width: 120%;
  right: 0px;
}

.overlay:hover .button0 {
  opacity: 1.0;
  top: 150px;
}

.overlay:hover .button2 {
  opacity: 1.0;
  right: 0px;
}

.stars {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transform: scale(0.0);
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #F58D00;
  top: 100px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
}

.stars1 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transform: scale(0.0);
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #F58D00;
  top: 50px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
}

.overlay:hover .stars1 {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.overlay:hover .stars {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 1.0;
}

button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.button0 {
  opacity: 0.0;
  position: relative;
  top: 166px;
}

.button2 {
  opacity: 0.0;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  right: 55px;
}

.overlay:hover .button1 {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 1.0;
  animation-name: button;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.button1 {
  transform: scale(0.0);
  opacity: 0.0;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

@keyframes button {
  0% {
    top: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 90px;
  }
}

.overlay h1 {
  font-family: belligiant, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  top: 120px;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
}

.overlay:hover h1 {
  font-family: belligiant, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  top: 70px;
}

.overlay p {
  top: 65px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: bold;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transform: scale(0.0);
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
}

.box:hover p {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.box1:hover p {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.box2:hover p {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.overlay {
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.69, 0, .38, .99);
  height: 350px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.box:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box1:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box1:hover {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0% {
    background-size: 140%;
  }
  30% {
    background-size: 120%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 140%;
  }
}

.box2:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.box2 h1,
.box2 p {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


}

/*END OFFERS*/

/* TESTIMONIALS */
.testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 1349px;
  height: 600px;
}
.testimonials .testimonials1 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 90px;
}
.testimonials .testimonials1 p {
  font-style: italic;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.image img {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* END TESTIMONIALS */

/* FOOTER */
.footer {
  background-image: url(offers.jpg);
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1349px;
  height: 300px;
}
.footer .logo1 {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 30%;
}
.mylogo {
  font-family: Belligiant, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  height: 60%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 80%;
}
.footer .logo1 p {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.footer .info {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 30%;
  height: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 60px 0 0 450px;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
.footer .info p {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
.copyright {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 267px;
  right: 1040px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

/*END FOOTER */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=yes;" />
  <title>St Martini</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restaurant.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <div class="header">
      <!--main part, inside are logo, na menu btns ect.. -->
      <div class="headcontent">
        <!--head contents -->

        <div class="nav">
          <!-- home btn, menu btn, reservation, shop, location, contact -->

          <div class="logo">
            <!--logo goes here -->
            <h1>St. <span>Martini</span></h1>
          </div>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Menu</a>
          <a href="#">Reservation</a>
          <a href="#">Shop</a>
          <a href="#">Location</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END NAVIGATION -->


      <!-- CONTENT -->
      <div class="actioncontent">
        <p>est. 2020</p>
        <h1>EAT. DRINK. ENJOY.</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="flex">
          <div class="btn1">
            <a class="link" href="#">Reserve Table</a>
          </div>
          <div class="btn2">
            <a class="link1" href="#">Browse Menu</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ENDE CONTENT -->

    <!-- SERVICES -->
    <div class="service">
      <div class="choose">
        <h1>Our Services</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          <br>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

        <div class="imgs">
          <img class="b" src="break.jpg" alt="">
          <img class="b" src="lunch.jpg" alt="">
          <img class="b" src="dinner.jpg" alt="">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SERVICES-->



    <!-- OFFERS -->
    <div class="offers">
      <div class="offers1">
        <h1>Something For <span>Everyone</span></h1>
        <hr>

        <br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          <br>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

      </div>

      <!-- Europe-->
      <div class="flex1">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h1>Europe</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Lasagne</p>
            <hr>
            <li class="stars">★★★★★</li>
            <button class="button0" type="button" name="button">Choose</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Europe-->

        <!--Asia-->
        <div class="box1">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h1>Asia</h1>
            <div class="border">
              <p>Sushi</p>
            </div>
            <li class="stars1">★★★★★</li>
            <button class="button1" type="button" name="button">Choose</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Asia-->

        <!-- America -->
        <div class="box2">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h1>America</h1>
            <hr class="hr">
            <p>Trout Amandin</p>
            <hr class="hr1">
            <li class="stars">★★★★★</li>
            <button class="button2" type="button" name="button">Choose</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- America -->


    <!-- END OFFERS -->


    <!-- TESTIMONIALS -->

    <div class="testimonials">
      <div class="testimonials1">
        <h1>Our Customer's Thoughts</h1>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="man.jpg" alt="">
          <img src="man1.jpg" alt="">
          <img src="woman.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <p style="padding-top: 20px">One of the best restaurants we´ve been to! <br> Highly Recomended</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END TESTIMONIALS -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="logo1">
        <h1 class="mylogo">St. <span>Martini</span></h1>
        <br>
        <p>Eat. Drink. Enjoy.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="info">

        <p> Adress: 4399 Moonlight Drive, <br> Atlantic City, New Jersey</p>

        <p>Call Us: +27 264 273 xx </p>


        <p>Email Us: Stmartini@martini.com</p>
      </div>
      <p class="copyright">© 2021 Your Company. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- FOOTER -->
</body>

</html>
```

The main goal is to achieve a responsive mobile screen where the page content fits perfectly to the mobile screen. I highly appreciate your help!

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYImc.jpg)
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BigBearBot/07uq4zbd/3/)

Comment: where exactly is the issue? I see no Media Queries. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck atm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The problem you face is due to the `width` CSS property that is set for various HTML elements. For example, it appears on the `header` element:

```
.header {
   ...
   width: 1349px;
}
```

One fundamental of Responsive Web Design is to never use fixed units like pixels since this would prevent the website to adapt to the viewport. Use relative units like `%`, `rems`, and `vm` (viewport width) instead of fixed units. To solve your problem, remove those `width` rules.